# Find if the query max'ed out the set time in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I am using maxTime to terminate the queries in mongo if it exceeds 1000ms.
Is there a way to find out if the query got terminated due to maxtime or it couldn't return any results due to match issues.

Comment: mongodb will throw exception if timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB will throw exception if query timeout.

Like this:

> error: { "$err" : "operation exceeded time limit", "code" : 50 }

Hence you are able to distinguish between the exception case and no result case.

[Read more here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxTimeMS/)